# Pytest passing test I think it should fail on sys.exit() call

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am trying to check the exit code I have for a script I'm writing in python3 on a Mac (10.14.4).  When I run the test it doesn't fail which I think is wrong.  But I can't see what it is that I've got wrong.

The test file looks like this:

```py
import pytest
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

import my_script

class TestMyScript():
    def test_exit(self):
         with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as pytest_wrapped_e:
            my_script.main()
            assert pytest_wrapped_e.type == SystemExit

    def test_exit_code(self):
         with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as pytest_wrapped_e:
            my_script.main()
            self.assertEqual(pytest_wrapped_e.exception.code, 42)
```

My script looks like:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

def main():
    print('Hello World!')
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output I get is:

```
$ py.test -v
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.3, pytest-3.10.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.9.0 -- /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/robertpostill/software/gateway, inifile:
plugins: shutil-1.6.0
collected 2 items

test/test_git_refresh.py::TestGitRefresh::test_exit PASSED               [ 50%]
test/test_git_refresh.py::TestGitRefresh::test_exit_code PASSED          [100%]

=========================== 2 passed in 0.02 seconds ===========================
$
```

I would expect the second test(test_exit_code) to fail as the exit call is getting a code of 0, not 42.  But for some reason, the assert is happy whatever value I put in the sys.exit call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question, that's because your `Asserts` are never called (either of them).  When `exit()` is called the program is done (at least within the `with` clause), it turns off the lights, packs up its bags, and goes home. No further functions will be called. To see this add an `assert` before and after you call `main`:

```
def test_exit_code(self):
     with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as pytest_wrapped_e:
        self.assertEqual(0, 1) # This will make it fail
        my_script.main()
        self.assertEqual(0, 1) # This will never be called because main `exits`
        self.assertEqual(pytest_wrapped_e.exception.code, 42)
```

A test *passes* if no asserts fail and nothing breaks, so in your case both tests passed because the `assert` was never hit.

To fix this pull your `asserts` out of the `with` statement:

```
def test_exit_code(self):
    with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as pytest_wrapped_e:
        my_script.main()
    self.assertEqual(pytest_wrapped_e.exception.code, 42)
```

Though now you will need to fix the `pytest` syntax because you are missing some other stuff.

See: [Testing sys.exit() with pytest](https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/testing-sys-exit-with-pytest-10c6e5f7726f)